# Why are we getting ".XML.OLD" files when compiling?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xml-documentation, visual-studio-2013

A large number of our projects (all of which have XML documentation turned on) generate `<assemblyname>.XML` files (as expected) and ALSO a copy of that file called `<assemblyname>.XML.OLD`

Not all of our projects which have XML documentation turned on generate this ".XML.OLD" file, but many of them do. There seems no rhyme or reason why some do and some don't...

Does anyone know why this is happening? And how to stop it happening?

This is with Visual Studio 2012. I also have Resharper 8 installed (a colleague has resharper 7, but still sees the ".xml.old" files).

Comment: What version of VS are you running? It might help to add that to your question

Comment: @MikyDinescu Good point, added!

Comment: Are you sure it's a copy of the new file and not just a backup of the previous file made because a new one is being generated? It's easy to check: Make a change in the XML documentation in your code, build again, and diff the .XML and .XML.OLD files to see if they're the same. If not, the .OLD is a backup of the previous documentation.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, I deleted the contents of the folder first, so it can't be that. Also, the two files are always identical. If I watch the folder as the compile proceeds, I can see the "xml" file being created early on, and then the ".xml.old" file being generated a little later. It's as if its trying to generate the xml docs twice, and the second time it sees an existing ".xml" file and renames it to ".old".

Comment: Any antivirus that might be interfering with deletion of temporary files?

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think that can be it - I deleted the entire folder first, and the ".xml.old" files are being generated on computers that have different virus checkers.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't seem to make this happen the way you describe. Does it happen if you create a new solution with XML docs enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when you are using [`Code Contracts`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) and you have selected the option to *Emit contracts into XML doc file*.

I expect that the Code Contracts rewriter is simply making a backup of the XML doc file because it is changing it.